# How to show currency using swift-currency in SwiftUI inside of Text() without "Optional" being shown?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to use the following library: https://github.com/peek-travel/swift-currency

Issue I am having is if I have a varible:

```
let dollaramount:USD = USD(1.88)
```

When I do:

```
Text(dollaramount) // I get errors about "Initializer 'Init(_:)' requires that 'USD' conform to 'StringProtocol'
```

When I try:

```
Text("\(dollaramount)") // I get error about "Instance method 'appendINterpolation' requires that 'USD' conform to '_FormatSpecifiable'
```

What I try:

```
Text("\(dollaramount.localizedString()).") // No errors, but the SwiftUI Text element shows "Optional(USD(1.17))"
```

What is the proper way to show the string so that i don't get all the Optional(USD(1.17)) and just show "$1.17" like it should? Also, is it right to use USD as the type for this kind of variable? I've read that float and double should not be used for currency. If USD is not the preferred type when doing a lot of currency procesing, please provide the correct alternative.

Comment: What happen if you use `dollaramount.description`?

Comment: Have you ever read the [swift-currency User Guide : Displaying Currency Values](https://github.com/peek-travel/swift-currency/blob/master/docs/Usage.md#displaying-currency-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since `localizedString()` return optional value. you can simply provide default value to avoid `nil`.

```swift
 Text("\(dollaramount.localizedString() ?? "My optional").")
```